# Looking for a hosting provider for Twitter bot that tweets once per day

Tags: twitter, hosting, bots

I'm building twitter bot that tweets once per day at a specific time. Code is written in JavaScript so it's basically one JS file that I need to invoke in Node.js everyday at that specific time.

I can't decide what hosting provider I should use. I was looking into Amazon WS and Google Cloud but both of them have very complicated documentation and I don't know what service I'm looking for (I don't have any experience with AWS nor GC yet).

Any guidance would be very appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the end I've figured out how to setup free hosting at Heroku and use their [scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to run my script every day at a certain hour.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your code in an [AWS Lambda with Scheduled event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) configured to execute the code at a given time of the day.

To deploy your code, the steps are straight forward since you only need to upload the zip of your code to a lambda function(Select Lambda after login into the AWS Console) or write the code using the inline editor. Make sure the callback and scheduled event is configured. If you need DevOps support to test the Lambda locally and deploy using command line you can use the [serverless framework](https://serverless.com).

This way you only pays per execution and because the Lambda free tier includes 1M free requests per month and 400,000 GB-seconds of compute time per month, your usage scenario most probably fall within the free tier.